# Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127

Tags: r, windows

I was trying to install package "stringi" using install.packages() but ran into the following errors:

```
PackDirB="C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.2\\stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz"

> install.packages(PackDirB, repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'stringi' ...

** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'stringi'

* removing 'C:/Users/Santos/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringi'
Warning messages:

1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 

"C:\Users\PC\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz"' had status 1 

2: In install.packages(PackDirB, repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What happened? What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [RTools installed](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html).  Installing RTools got rid of this error for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally speaking link-only answers are not acceptable. The question of RTools being installed should really be a comment on the post. Can you either expand this to a full answer or delete and make it a comment?

Comment: I know that this wont help, but instaling RTools in my case didn't help.